# How can I add and image or svg next to node?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I want to add an image, svg or even create a THREE figure next to some nodes on a floorplan.

Here's how I'm getting the position of a node `dbId`

```
function getLeafFragIds(model, leafId) {
            const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
            const fragIds = [];

            instanceTree.enumNodeFragments( leafId, function( fragId ) {
                fragIds.push( fragId );
            });

            return fragIds;
        }

        function getComponentGeometry( viewer, dbId ) {

            const fragIds = getLeafFragIds( viewer.model, dbId );

            let matrixWorld = null;

            const meshes = fragIds.map( function( fragId ) {

                const renderProxy = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy( viewer.model, fragId );

                const geometry = renderProxy.geometry;
                const attributes = geometry.attributes;
                const positions = geometry.vb ? geometry.vb : attributes.position.array;

                const indices = attributes.index.array || geometry.ib;
                const stride = geometry.vb ? geometry.vbstride : 3;
                const offsets = geometry.offsets;

                matrixWorld = matrixWorld || renderProxy.matrixWorld.elements;

                return {
                    positions,
                    indices,
                    offsets,
                    stride
                };
            });

            return {
                matrixWorld,
                meshes
            };
        }
```

Is there a way that can be useful to place or draw something next to the node? I've seen some code related with `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture();` and `setMaterial()` but the problem is that I don't know how to define the exact position next to the node

If we talk about a geometric figure like this:

```
let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

How do I define the position of it near to the `node`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the position of a node by calculating the center of its bounding box and the easiest way to do is with the Viewer's built-in unities:

```
viewer.select(nodeid); //select the target component so the selector knows which component to fit selection bounds
const box = viewer.utilities.getBoundingBox();
const position = box.center();
viewer.select(); //clear selection if necessary
```